# no option to add an APN

Tags: settings, 9.0-pie, apn

I brought a new phone recently (Blackview A60 Pro) and while calls and texts work fine, I can't access the internet. I spoke to my network provider (Talkmobile) who said that I need to add an APN.

However, for some reason, the option to add one is missing from my phone. There is no + sign and the 3 dots doesn't bring up an option to add an APN. The current APNs can't be edited as well. I've attached screenshots as well.

I downloaded myAPN but it didn't work on my phone and I'm not sure what else to do. Would really appreciate any help with this as I'm quite stuck and have tried everything.

[image: .]
[image: .]
.[image: .]
[image: .]

Comment: Is the phone branded by Vodafone? May be this is some sort of "network lock" using the APN config? Or is this a company device, managed by an MDM?

Comment: Nope. it's supposed to be unlocked. I brought it from Amazon so it's not linked to any network or company.

Comment: Are you sure the SIM card is in the correct slot. Dual SIM phones often only allow data traffic using the primary SIM. Additionally I would check if the device the device you bought was genuine. Compare the IMEI on the packing with the one displayed on the phone. May be someone bought the phone, replaced it with a branded one and sent it to back to Amazon.

Comment: Tried changing the sim slot and unfortunately it didn't do anything. Also checked the IMEI and it all matches up. Really not sure what else I could check.

Comment: [Try instructions as in this video](https://youtu.be/dbnfB2guBhA)

Answer (score 0):

Have had the same problem. Thought it was the Blackview (A80 Pro) but when tried a different network's sim it worked perfectly. The APN's should get populated when the network is selected. In my case TalkMobile it did not populate the APN's. Put an EE sim in and it worked instantly. Have ordered a new sim so we shall see.

Answer (score 0):

just saw this post whilst searching for an answer to the same problem with an A80pro, i now appear to have cured my problem with internet access and don't know whether yours maybe similiar but having tried everything i could think of including attempting to change the APN settings which was impossible I discovered that by swiping down from the top of the screen several icons appeared including one for mobile data and one for wifi. by turning off the wifi one and ensuring that the mobile data one was on everything suddenly worked! I hasten to add that i was unaware of this screen but that i had ensured that the mobile data option and the data roaming option in the settings menu were turned on, why on earth there are 2 options re mobile data God only knows as to me it doesnt make sense but if anyone knows a good reason i'd be pleased to hearit!